# MySQL query using info from seperate tables

Tags: mysql

I have a rather complex SQL query that I am looking for a little help with.

I have two tables: a history table and a details table.

The history table contains the following columns.

```
Event Date(ev_date) 
Event Code(ev_code)  
Machine ID(mc_id)
```

The Details table contains the following columns:

```
Machine ID(mc_id), 
Location ID(lo_id) 
Machine Name(mc_name)
```

I need a query that returns the count of the number of events from the history table between a given date range of a given group of machines given by Location ID.

So, kinda in sudo code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM history 
WHERE ev_date (BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) AND ev_code = 1 AND ????
```

(mc_id must have certain lo_id from details table).

Does this make sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM history h
    WHERE h.ev_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
        AND ev_code = 1
        AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                       FROM details d
                       WHERE h.mc_id = d.mc_id
                           AND d.lo_id = @LocationID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a one-to-one mapping between `history` and `details` on `mc_id`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM history h
JOIN details d USING mc_id
WHERE h.ev_code = 1
AND h.ev_date between start_date and end_date
AND d.lo_id IN (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

Alternatively `ON h.mc_id = d.mc_id` instead of `USING mc_id`.

Comment: Ill have to try this one as well.  Thanks for the response.